# MATLAB filter and conv Functions

Tags: matlab, filters, convolution, cross-correlation

I'm trying to get familiar with MATLAB's filter and conv functions. To start, I created a signal that was 1000 zeroes followed by a 13 sample long Barker code. I then convolved it with the same Barker code flipped around to get the cross correlation, which resulted in a signal with a delta function at sample 1013.

Next I tried the same operation, but instead of calculating the cross correlation of the signal with the Barker code, I calculated the cross correlation of the signal with a the Barker code delayed by 100 samples with a value of 0. I expected the result to be a delta function at sample 1113, but the delta was still at sample 1013. Why would that be?

Finally, I tried filtering the signal with MATLAB's filter function. I used the 13 sample long Barker code for b and 1 for a. The result did not look like a delta function, with one peak at sample 1005, another at 1012, and quite a bit of variation in between. Why is that the result? Shouldn't the filter function produce a delta at sample 1013?

Below is my code and an image of my results.

```
barker13 = [1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1];

signal = [zeros(1, 1000) barker13];

correlation1 = conv(fliplr(barker13), signal);
correlation2 = conv(fliplr([zeros(1, 100) barker13]), signal);

filtered = filter(barker13, [1], signal);

subplot(3,1,1);
plot(correlation1);
title('Filtered with conv Command');

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(correlation2);
title('Filtered with conv Command, Delayed 100 Samples');

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(filtered);
title('Filtered with filter Command');
```

[image]

Comment: `filtered = filter(barker13, [1], signal);` should be `filtered = filter(fliplr(barker13), [1], signal);`

Comment: See also: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403698/what-is-the-difference-between-filter-and-conv-in-matlab) or here [SE.DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34445/implementing-fir-with-matlab) and finally at [maltab](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/filter-implementation-and-analysis.html)